# jquery enter submit function textarea how do it?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, i want to enter submit function how do it?thank you

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="jquery.js"></script>
 <form id="submit">
 <textarea ID="UPDATE"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" id="saveResult" value="Save All Data" />
 </form>
 <div id="displayResult"></div>
 <script>
 $("#saveResult").click(function(){   
 var firstname = $("#update").val();
 lastname =  $("#lname").val() ;
 $.post("tes.asp",{update2:firstname,LName2:lastname} , function(data) {
 $("#displayResult").html(data);
 });
  $('#update').val('');$('#lname').val(''); 
  });</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _enter submit function_? Submitting form on pressing Enter key?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#submit").submit(function() { ... });
```

The `submit` event is triggered when the form is submitted either by clicking on a button or when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the last field.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood the question correctly.

So if you want to enable form submit when users hit enter on their keyboard,

```
//caching the target form element
var targetForm = $('#someformID');
targetForm .find('input').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    targetForm.focus().submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it ask what you answered.  Figured that was better than leaving it ambiguous and have no good answer..